# Python filewriting with write(), writelines(), to_csv() not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, tor, file-writing

I'm running a piece of code which takes input from a txt file, uses the input to scrape a tor webpage and then gives a list of strings called result. I'm using the tbselenium module. I need to write this list to two output files valid.txt and address.txt, when i run the script i get the result (a list of strings) but nothing is written to the two output files. There is no error raised and the print statements inside the two functions work perfectly. The input is read successfully

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd

def read_input():
    with open('Entries.txt') as fp:
        users = fp.readlines()
    return users

users = read_input()
result = some_function(users) # This function scrapes the webpage using selenium

def write_output(result):
    with open('valid.txt', 'a+') as fw:
        fw.writelines(result)
        print('Writing to valid.txt', result)


def write_addr(result):
    with open('address.txt', 'a+') as fw:
        for x in result:
            fw.write(x.split(':')[5]+'\n')
            print('Writing to address.txt')

write_output(result)
write_addr(result)
```

I then tried writing the same output to a csv file.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
df.to_csv('valid.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

The dataFrame is created but nothing is written to the csv file. It is not even created if i haven't already created one in my folder.
If i don't run the scraping function and try to write something to the output files then it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

def write_output(result):
    with open('valid.txt', 'a+') as fw:
        fw.writelines(result)
        print('Writing to valid.txt', result)


def write_addr(result):
    with open('address.txt', 'a+') as fw:
        for x in result:
            fw.write(x.split(':')[5]+'\n')
            print('Writing to address.txt')

result = ['I am :scrap:ed d:ata:from tor wit:h add:ress:es\n', 'I am :scrap:ed d:ata:from tor wit:h add:ress:es\n', 'I am :scrap:ed d:ata:from tor wit:h add:ress:es\n']

write_output(result)
write_addr(result)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
df.to_csv('valid.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

I didn't find any problem with your code (at least not with the write functions you have for creating valid.txt, addrress.txt, and valid.csv).
I have tested your code with my own dummy result. As seen from the attached images, the respective files were created successfully. I suspect the error might be from your result list. You should also check to make sure the 5th index after the split(':') is not a space character and note that the files will be created in the directory the python script is opened from (in case you are looking for the files in the wrong directory). Other than these the desired functions should run properly provided your result is returned from your web scraping function.
Cheers

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting the correct result and it's being passed correctly to the write_output function. When i give random result without running the selenium scraping part of the code, the files are written correctly else not.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. While running the selenium driver, it changes the current working directory to the directory where the tor browser is located and hence all the files are being
saved there.